# Why am I getting an error while concatenating 2 strings?

Tags: c, pointers

I know that dest is a pointer and it holds the address of dest[0], ie *dest would give me dest[0]
so I basically wanted to change the value of (dest+l)(which is currently having address of '\0') to the
address of src[0], but I am getting weird outputs.

dest=final works then why does this code snippet fail?

```
char* strcat(char* dest, char*src){
    char* final;
    int l=strlen(dest);
    final=dest;
    int b=0,i;
    char* ans;
    final+=l;
    final=src;
    final-=l;
    dest=final;
    printf("%s",final);
    return dest;

}
```

EDIT:
after reading the comments I made some changes to my code but now it gives me RE

```
char* strct(char* dest, char*src){
    char** final;
    int l=strlen(dest);
    *final=dest;
    int b=0,i;
    char* ans;
    final+=l;
    *final=src;
    final-=l;
    printf("%s",*final);
    return *final;
}
```

Comment: You don't actually append `src` to `dest`, you just *reassign* `final` to make it point to where `src` is pointing. And then do some pointer arithmetic which might put `final` out of bounds of `src`.

Comment: yep i got your point, thanks

Comment: Ig I will need pointer to pointer

Comment: No, you need a *loop* to copy from `src` into the end of `dest`.

Comment: Oh but cant it be done only with pointers

Comment: No it's not possible.

Comment: I didnt want to use loops, since we have learnt pointers recently

Comment: okay got your point, thanks

Comment: Would you mind writing an answer explaining the reason why this method is not working? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pointer to pointer version added nothing but extra stars and extra bugs, so lets ignore that one...

Now, what does the original code do:

- `final=dest;` Now `final` points at `dest`.
- `final+=l;` Now `final` points at the null terminator in `dest`.
- `final=src;` Now `final` points at `src` and it forgets all about pointing at `dest`. This doesn't make sense.
- Instead of `final=src` you should have done `strcpy(final, src);`. This assuming that `dest` is large enough to contain the `src` string to begin with.

A simpler implementation would be:

```
char* strcat (char* dest, const char* src)
{
  strcpy(dest+strlen(dest), src);
  return dest;
}
```

This is essentially the very same thing as you attempted, just less verbose.

Comment: But but, final stores the memory addresses right? then final would contain address of final[0], similarly final[l] would contain address of '\0', so aren't we simply telling that final should contain address of src[0], by final+=l; final=src;... some type of a linked list I mean.. where we basically use pointers in this fashion

Comment: @Alex Think of it this way: you have two queues of people in the supermarket. You are tasked with merging them into one so that one cash register can close. Now you could point with your hand at the beginning of the first queue, the end of it, point wherever you want. Still the queues won't actually merge until the people you point at start moving. That is, the actual data. And this is arrays, so it has nothing whatsoever to do with how linked lists behave.

Comment: Yes yes got your point thanks, it is just that the arrays are contiguously stored, not like they have any connection with each other, thanks a lot!